# AWS ECS and Load Balancing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, elastic-load-balancer

I see that ECS services can use Application Load Balancers, and the dynamic port stuff works atuomagically. However, an ALB has a maximum of 10 rules other than default rules. Does that mean that I need a separate ALB for every 10 services unless I wish to access via a different port (in which case the default rules would kick in)? This seems obvious, but for something touted to be the solution to load balancing in a microservices environment, this would seem incredibly limiting. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know and have experienced, this is indeed true, you are limited to 10 listeners per ALB. Take into account that this setup (ALB + ECS) is fairly new so it is possible that Amazon will adjust the limits as people are requesting this.

Take into account as well that a listener typically has multiple targets, in a microservice architecture this translates to multiple instances of the same service. So you can run 10 different services but you are able to run 10 instances of each service, balancing 100 containers with a single ALB.

Alternatively (to save costs) you could create one listener with multiple rules, but they have to be distinguished by path pattern and have to listen (not route to) the same port. Rules can forward to a target group of your choice. E.g. you can route /service1 to container 1 and /service2 to container 2 within one listener.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct, and it is a low restriction. However if you are able to use different CNAMES for your services then having them in an ALB with single target group for each service won't behave differently to having one ALB and multiple target groups each with rules. Dynamic ports are probably the main part of their "microservices solution" argument.